# Como evitar a instalação do Apache, quando instalando php7.1 no Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, php-7.1

Tenho o seguinte código que instala o php7.1 no Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
#Modules
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-cli 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-common 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-json 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-opcache 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-mysql 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-mbstring 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-mcrypt 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-zip 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-fpm
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-xml
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-xmlrpc
#sudo apt-get install -y php-token-stream
```

Como se observa abaixo, ele tbm instala o Apache, e não oferece opções.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu interesse é utilizar o NGINX e não o Apache.

Por isso gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira para instalar o php7.1 sem passar pela instalação do apache?

Comment: Tentou instalar cada módulo em separado para ver qual é que está adicionando o Apache?

Comment: Simples, é só instalar o **Nginx** `sudo apt install nginx`, se não tiver instalado, e não executar o comando `sudo apt-get install -y php7.1` e pronto.

Answer (score 0):

O `php7.1`, por padrão, já vem com o apache, é possível remove-lo, mas...

1. Você pode usar o `apt-get remove apache2* && apt-get purge apache2`
2. Você pode "[buildar](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.nginx.php)" o `PHP` manualmente.

Mas você pode instalar o `php7.1-fpm` também.

Comment: Oi Valdeir, acho q a . melhor maneira vai ser desahbilitar o Apache.  Valeu